# How to configure svn with RFT?

Tags: svn, automated-tests, rft

I want to setup SVN with my RFT project. How can I do that? 
I had tried through

**Help-->Install New Software-->All Available Sites**

But Svn plugin is not coming Attached Screenshot as well

[image]

Environment:

- Window 8
- RFT version 8.6

Comment: Please ask a single question at a time.  Also, all three of these questions are [off-topic according to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Patrick ok I will update my question

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Updated

Comment: @PatrickQuirk in FAQ read step number 4

Comment: This question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for asking questions about **specific** problems, so please be sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and include a [mcve].

Comment: What is your problem? Where did you get troubles?Why do not you use your own mind for its intended purpose?

Comment: @LazyBadger  I had tried through
Help-->Install New Software-->All Available Sites
But Svn plugin is not coming Attached Screenshot as well. Please Help

Comment: @ScottWeldon Question Updated I had tried through
Help-->Install New Software-->All Available Sites
But Svn plugin is not coming Attached Screenshot as well. Please Help

Comment: Are there any Software Sites in the Available Software Sites List?

Comment: @Roland No Software sites are available. If I had tried directly add the url then below error occured  ==> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.provisionexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to install a SVN client in Rational Functional Tester is to use the Eclipse Marketplace and to search for either subclipse oder subversive. Open Marketplace:

[image]

If there is no Eclipse Marketplace installed you need to install it first. For doing so, you need to add the Eclipse Luna Repository (I think Functional Tester 8.6 is based on this version) to your available software sites:

[image]

Filter for Marketplace...

Another way than using Eclipse Marketplace is to install the plugin directly, as described on the plugins homepage: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki.